# Overriding of results in nested for loops

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a situation there I need to run nested loops

Issue is when parent loop started response what i get and assign things are fine. so child loop is done.
Now parent loop is incremented then child loop response are overridden and getting other response instead of expected.

here is the sample code

```
 for (var j = items.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {

  for (var i = response.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

      if (response[i].id ==
          items[j]._id && response[i].posid ==
          posevntDetial._id) {
//suppose when j is 0 and i is 2 then i get perfect response later when j is 1 then all data going to else... statements
          if (response[i].timein && response[i].timeout && response[i].title == "Check-Out") {

              items[j].Title = "Check-Out";
          } else if (response[i].timein && response[i].timeout && response[i].title != "Check-Out") {

              items[j].Title = "Check-In";

          } else if (response[i].timein && !response[i].timeout && response[i].level == "on") {
              items[j].Title = "Check-Out";
          }

      } else {
          items[j].Title = "Check-In";
      }

  }
 }
```

Finally i get all my titles as checkin. Help would be appreciated . Thank you.

Comment: Can you prove some example input/output?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to have happen here? In your inner loop you are setting `items[j].Title` which is obviously the same property regardless of which value of `i` you have.

Comment: yes @MattBurland I'm trying to set that title field dynamically based on those conditions to show it on button in html.

Comment: There is zero point to your inner loop. The value of `items[j].Title` will always be whatever it was when `i==0`.

Comment: Lets say i have 5 users (Parent loop ). I made 2 check-in's (inserted into db and the response is child loop). Now the thing is I'm trying to show those 2 checkin users as checkout on my button dynamically. The thing is it is not happening i get only 1 user as checkout from above code but it should be 2.   What ever the Results are in last iteration is assigned to title.

Comment: yes @MattBurland those are my results I don't want that to be happen so pls tell me what should i do...